# How to send FCM notification in recipient time zone?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Using cloud functions, how to send an FCM notification on a specific topic at a scheduled time of **recipient time zone**?
I can see that option in notification composer in firebase console, but is there any helper method to send it through code?

[image: Notification Composer]

Comment: There is no simple "helper method".  What you're trying to do seems far more complex than an API call would allow.  You will need to understand all the timezones for all your users, and somehow schedule a function to execute at the relevant time for each of those timezones, querying your database for, and targeting all the users who you believe to be in that TZ.

Comment: Okay I understand. But if that's possible from firebase console, I wonder why shouldn't it be possible from cloud functions  

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. I'm saying you have a lot of work in front of you to duplicate what the console is doing.

Comment: Yes @Doug, I do understand that it's not straightforward to implement the entire logic! My point was it would be great if admin sdk or cloud functions could provide some helper method for achieving the same functionality for sending notification in recipient time zone as that in notification composer in firebase console

Comment: Then feel free to file a feature request.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features